# Print the result of evaluation of an expression in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, expression, evaluation

Consider a simple if/else block in Python like the one below:

```
if x:
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

Where x could be a comparison, a condition or simply a string/list/object. How can I open a python shell and find out what `if x` would evaluate to without writing the loop? i.e. is `x` `True` or `False` for a certain corner case value.

For example, if x is an empty list. Can I open python shell, assign `x = []` and then write `print <function of x>` that'll output `True` or `False` on execution. What is that `<function of x>`?

I feel I'm asking a rather silly question and can't think straight right now but I often find myself opening a shell, assign a corner case value to a variable and write an if/else to see what corner values would evaluate to `True`/`False`. I'm just looking for a shorter way to find out on the shell, without writing the 4-line loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the function `bool`.

```
>>> bool([])
False   
>>> bool(['monty'])
True
```

What the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) say.

> Convert a value to a Boolean, using the standard truth testing
>   procedure. If x is false or omitted, this returns False; otherwise it
>   returns True. bool is also a class, which is a subclass of int. Class
>   bool cannot be subclassed further. Its only instances are False and
>   True.

Comment: Yes, precisely that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your four lines should be the same as

`print(bool(x))`

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for.